# servlet init method fails to create mysql tables - why?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

my java servlet init method fails to create mysql tables - I'd like to know why. When I log on to mysql directly and create the tables life is beautiful, when I delete the tables and run the servlet - no tables, servlet throws an exception (haven't quite dug that up yet).The code looks like this:

```
package ...;
import ... // quite a bit
@WebServlet("/MyClass") 
public class MyClass extends HttpServlet {
          public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {     Foo foo = Foo.getInstance();
                    foo.createTables();  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException("Error creating tables", e);         
            }
      }
```

... // more MyClass stuff
}
    //Foo is a singleton that looks like this:

```
    package ...;
    import ... // quite a bit
public class Foo {
  public static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

  public static Foo getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
```

... // more Foo stuff, then

```
public void createTables(){
 try {

        // first establish a connection
 Connection connection = Foo.getInstance().getConnection(); // get connection est.
```

// est. connection to dbase - works well once the tables are set up

```
 //Create a query. 
 Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 

    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS survey (uuid_Survey VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, "+
    "top VARCHAR(40), " +
    " likert VARCHAR(40), "+
    " numerical VARCHAR(40), "+
    " open VARCHAR(40), " +
    " KEY ix_survey_uuid (uuid_Survey), "+
    " PRIMARY KEY (uuid_Survey))";

 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( query ); 
     query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (" +
    "uuid_Survey VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, "+
    "remoteAddress VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, " +
    "currentTime BIGINT NOT NULL, "+
    " likert VARCHAR(40),"+
    " numerical DOUBLE, " +
    " open VARCHAR(40),  "+
    " PRIMARY KEY (uuid_Survey, remoteAddress, currentTime),"+
    "FOREIGN KEY ix_survey_uuid (uuid_Survey) REFERENCES survey (uuid_Survey))" ;

 rs = stmt.executeQuery( query );  

 connection.close();

 } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating tables: " + e);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Stop catching and hiding exceptions. At least print their stack trace, to know what and where the problem is.

Comment: I'm still looking for it - I've written the servlet to go to an error page which unfortunately is not very informative (it has null where I was hoping the error message etc. would appear).  Looking through my tomcat log I can't find anything helpful.

Comment: You don't find anything helpful because, as I said, you're explicitely preventing something helpful to be printed. Replace `System.err.println("Error creating tables: " + e);` by `throw new RuntimeException(e);`, or at least by `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: I tried putting in e.printStackTrace(); but the jsp error page is still not showing anything useful.  catalina log still not showing anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `stmt.executeQuery( query );`

As the [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) says-

`ResultSet#executeQuery(String sql)` - This method executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object. where *sql* - an SQL statement to be sent to the database, typically a static **SQL SELECT statement**

You might want to use [execute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) instead

Like `stmt.execute(query);`

or

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS survey (uuid_Survey VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,"+
        "top VARCHAR(40), " +
        " likert VARCHAR(40), "+
        " numerical VARCHAR(40), "+
        " open VARCHAR(40), " +
        " KEY ix_survey_uuid (uuid_Survey), "+
        " PRIMARY KEY (uuid_Survey))";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
int count = statement.executeUpdate();
if(count>=0){
    System.out.println("Successfully created.");
}
```